# Error in Django - [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified - Django

Tags: python, django, directory

The problem is: Im trying to let users upload 5 images and on uploading I want them to change directory.

So far my views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "product/add_product.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_class = ProductForm
    login_url = "/login/"


    # Save current user id as product_user_id in DB

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):

        form.instance.product_user_id = self.request.user.id
        response = super().form_valid(form)

        id = form.instance.id
        picture_1 = form.instance.product_img_1
        picture_2 = form.instance.product_img_2
        picture_3 = form.instance.product_img_3
        picture_4 = form.instance.product_img_4
        picture_5 = form.instance.product_img_5
        product_title = form.instance.product_title
        user = form.instance.product_user_id

        # Change directory

        new_directory = change_directory(id, product_title, user, picture_1, picture_2, picture_3, picture_4, picture_5)

        return new_directory
```

utils.py

```
def change_directory(id, product_title, user, picture_1, picture_2, picture_3, picture_4, picture_5):

    file_name = f"{id}-{product_title}-{product_title}-{user}"
    new_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "product_images", file_name)

    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.makedirs(new_path)

    picture_list = [picture_1, picture_2, picture_3, picture_4, picture_5]

    for i in picture_list:
        old_image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, f"product_images/{i}")
        new_image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, f"product_images/{file_name}/{i}")
        os.rename(old_image_path, new_image_path)               

    return new_path
```

The solution is not far away, but im out of ideas.

If this helps:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_description_short = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    product_condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_location_state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_location_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_delivery_time = models.IntegerField()
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    product_img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    product_img_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    product_img_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    product_img_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    product_img_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    product_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
        'product_title',
        'product_description',
        'product_description_short',
        'product_condition',
        'product_code',
        'product_manufacturer',
        'product_location_state',
        'product_location_city',
        'product_delivery_time',
        'product_category',
        'product_img_1',
        'product_img_2',
        'product_img_3',
        'product_img_4',
        'product_img_5',
        'price'
        ]
```

Error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\rener\OneDrive\Desktop\Web developer bootcamp\Enda projektid\Ecom\project-ecom\ecom\media\product_images/product_images/DSC_0922_yhSMaeD.JPG' -> 'C:\Users\rener\OneDrive\Desktop\Web developer bootcamp\Enda projektid\Ecom\project-ecom\ecom\media\product_images/15-Autouus-Autouus-2/product_images/DSC_0922_yhSMaeD.JPG'

Im expecting it to first upload to product_images folder and after that move them to product_images/{file_name} folder.

Comment: Your old path seems to contain `product_images/product_images`, is that on purpose? It might be clearer if you give an example of what you expect an old and new path to be.

Comment: No it wasn't. And thank you, it gave me a lead where to start looking. I wanted save product images to different folder than root, with specific folder names.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time searching from internet I found a little bit different way to save images to different folder than root. It's much faster and easier way, but unfortunately with this method you won't have access to product's id.

I've create a new function which is creating a path for uploaded images using values form field product_title and user's id value product_user.id.

```
def new_image_path(instance, filename):
    
    return f'product_images/{instance.product_title}-{instance.product_user.id}_user/{filename}'
```

Next I added function new_image_path to Imagefield upload path. Now it is uploading images to a path which the function is returning to.

```
product_img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
```

As I understand there is no way to get product id before saving it, but it's possible to access to other fields.

Comment: Hi Emerica11, welcome to SO. While the information in your link may solve the question, link-only answer are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained. Thanks